# Burn token using blockfrost java sdk?

Tags: native-assets, blockfrost, javascript, java, burn

Does anyone have an example how to burn a NFT using the blockfrost.io java SDK or Javascript SDK?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is a great post on the Cardano form that goes in-depth on different types of burning methods [[1](https://forum.cardano.org/t/proof-of-burn-smart-contract/79540/27)]. Note that these tokens send to such addresses still exists but can't be transferred anymore by anyone. But for some of the solutions mentioned one can proof that the address corresponds to a unspendable script.

Answer (score 0):

There is an explanation of burning tokens on [Github](https://github.com/Emurgo/cardano-serialization-lib/issues/320#issuecomment-1101357333).

It's using `cardano-serialization-lib ^10`, the latest version. So it's very useful.

Comment: This tutorial assumes that the minting policy allows the action of burning. This may not be the case. In the case that the minting policy allowed you link to burn this works, its just minting with negative value. If the policy is locked or not accessible by you (for example only certain key holders can burn), then you can indefinitely lock your tokes like above mentioned (just like burning).

Comment: ok, thank you very much for your clarification!

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, there is no support for burning tokens out of box yet.

You might want to look at [this specific part of the pull request to the transaction builder](https://github.com/Emurgo/yoroi-frontend/pull/2460/files#diff-d81942726304f72064a9fd4640adb33b987f87127e25824af19510f0de0625a9R329) to get an inspiration on how to do that.